# jQuery click event not firing in IE 7/8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

This is the a tag which has a class with a background image:

```
            <a id="PLAY" class="Play_Unmarked">
            </a>
```

The class itself:

```
.Play_Unmarked{border:0px;display: block;background-image:url('images/tomgui3_07.png');background-repeat:no-repeat;width:206px;height:44px;text-decoration:none;}
```

Event handeling:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.Play_Unmarked').click(function(d){
alert("Okay");
 });
});
```

Everything is fine in FF, IE9 and Chrome.. why is it not firing in ie7/8?

Comment: Not sure of its effect, but should you really have the `d` parameter in your click event handler?

Comment: i'm using it later to prevent defualt action..

Comment: tried to remove it.. not working also

Comment: Works fine for me on IE8/IE8-emulating IE7 on win7 see http://jsfiddle.net/m8sy6/

Comment: so maybe something is breaking it even before hand..oh god

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine for me on IE6/7/8 , give it a try from here please: http://jsfiddle.net/QbEDr/

don't forget to let us know if it work.

Comment: this workd in the jsfiddle.. not for me probably because something else.. thanks very much

Comment: if you can, post your full html so I can investigate more in this issue, but glade that it worded for you on jsfiddle :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe elder IEs do not recognize `<a>`s without `href`s or `name`s

Comment: what if you replaced the <a> with a <span> for example, and try again this code.